# Update and search in multi field properties in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to use multi field properties for multi language support. I created following mapping for this:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "product": {
      "properties": {
        "prod-id": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "prod-name": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "en": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "english"
            },
            "fr": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "french"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I created test record:

```
{
  "prod-id": "1234567",
  "prod-name": [
      "Test product",
      "Produit d'essai"
  ]  
}
```

and tried to query using some language:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
               {"match": {
                  "prod-name.en": "Produit"
               }}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

As a result I got my document. But I expected that I will have empty result when I use French but choose English. It seems ElasticSearch ignores which field I specified in query. There is no difference in search result when I use "prod-name.en" or "prod-name.fr" or just "prod-name". Is this behaviour expected? Should I do some special things to have searching just in one language?

Another problem with updating multi field property. I can't update just one field.

```
{
     "doc" : {
        "prod-name.en": "Test"
     }
}
```

I got following error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
            "reason": "Field name [prod-name.en] cannot contain '.'"
         }
      ],
      "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason": "Field name [prod-name.en] cannot contain '.'"
   },
   "status": 400
}
```

Is there any way to update just one field in multi field property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your mapping, the `prod-name.en` field will simply be analyzed using the `english` analyzer and the same for the french field. However, ES will not choose for you which value to put in which field.

Instead, you need to modify your mapping like this

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "product": {
      "properties": {
        "prod-id": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "prod-name": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "en": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "english"
            },
            "fr": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "french"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and input document to be like this and you'll get the results you expect.

```
{
  "prod-id": "1234567",
  "prod-name": {
      "en": "Test product",
      "fr": "Produit d'essai"
  }  
}
```

As for the updating part, your partial document should be like this instead.

```
{
     "doc" : {
        "prod-name": {
            "en": "Test"
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Val! You realy helped me! Your solution works great!